# how to import only the class methods in python

Tags: python

I have a GP.py file that I am then running a MyBot.py file from.

In the MyBot.py file, I have the line

```
from GP import *
```

I have a suspicion it is importing the whole file instead of just the class methods and class descriptions I want. In the GP.py file, There is code in addition to the defintions

Comment: It *is* importing the whole file. There is no way to avoid that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot import class methods separately, you have to import the classes. You can do this by enumerating the classes you want to import:

```
from GP import class1, class2, class3
```

Note that this will still load the entire module. This always happens if you import anything from the module. If you have code in that module that you do not want to be executed when the module is imported, you can protect it like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # put code here
```

Code inside the block will only be executed if the module is run directly, not if it is imported.

Answer (score 5):

> `_single_leading_underscore`: weak "internal use" indicator.  E.g. `from M import *` does not import objects whose name starts with an
>   underscore.

Use this instead:

```
from GP import SomeClass
```

Have a look at [PEP-8 (Python Guidelines)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) if you want to use `import *`

> Modules that are designed for use via `from M import *` should use the
>   `__all__` mechanism to prevent exporting globals

Answer (score 4):

It is not recommended to import all from a module. Zen of Python says "Explicit is better than Implicit"

It may have some side effects by overriding an existing name. You should always keep control on the namespace.

You can import your classes and function this way:

```
from GP import MyClass, my_function
```

An alternative is to import the module itself

```
import GP
GP.my_function()
GP.MyClass()
```

This way, you create a namespace for the GP module and avoid to overwrite something.

I hope it helps

Comment: from module import * can be used properly, given some guidelines, like only ust it in one file. It do take some care to do so, depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

import * indeed import all classes, functions,variables and etc..

if you want to import only specific class use

```
from GP import class_name
```

and as far as i know you cannot import only class methods

Answer (score -4):

If you want to import just some methods from class

```
from GP.MyClass import MyFunction
```