# accessing modules imported into __init__ without directly referencing them

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

If I make a `test_folder.__init__` that consists of:

```
constant1 = 1
from test_folder import moduleVar1
```

and then from the parent directory, run the following script:

```
import sys
from test_folder import constant1
print(constant1)
print(sys.modules)
```

`sys.modules` tells me that `test_folder.moduleVar1` was imported.

Output from `sys.modules`:

```
'test_folder.moduleVar1': <module 'test_folder.moduleVar1' from 'C:...\test_folder\moduleVar1.py'>
```

Why is this module shown as being imported when I haven't specified it to be imported?

Comment: I think it's done automatically. Each time any python code is modified and saved, it's recompiled. You can make some tests, like adding `print` to check if `db_migrate.py` takes updated models or not

Comment: I think this response satisfies your question [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8502348/3710490](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8502348/3710490)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing looks correct.  You can't import just a single variable.  The entire `__init__` module will be imported, along with the additional import.  Note that `sys.modules` does not indicate that something has been imported into the current namespace, and has no relation to the current namespace.   Essentially, `sys.modules` is a global dictionary (or cache) that Python uses to be sure that if you import a module more than once, or refer to its submodules, that it does not have to reload the module, and that it will not load the same module from two different places.

So, if a module is loaded *anywhere* in any of the modules or libraries your code accesses, it will remain in `sys.modules` thereafter.

So, in your main routine, when you say:

```
import sys
from test_folder import constant1
```

It is loading your `__init__` in order to access `constant1`, but since the `__init__` code also imports `moduleVar1`, python will make an entry in `sys.modules` as a record keeping entry even though it is not imported into your main module, so you'll see the residual entry if you print out `sys.modules`.