# Difference between the import(s) in python

Tags: python, python-import

What is the difference between:

```
from class_name import function_name
```

and:

```
import class_name
```

Please specify if for the first one only the `function_name` is imported and for the second the full class.

Comment: Duplicate: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/import-module-vs-from-module-import-function

Answer (score 0):

You can't import single methods from a class, only classes from modules or functions from modules. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502287/how-to-import-only-the-class-methods-in-python) question and [this tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).